# Google Map Is Not Resizing Properly

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm developing an application, where in I've included the `google maps`.
The `script` is as follows.

```
<script>https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false</script>
<script>
   $(function() {
     var map;

     function initialize() {

        var mapOptions = {
              zoom: 8,
              center: new google.maps.LatLng(13.004558, 77.6017),
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
               mapOptions);
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");

     });

</script>
```

And the `div` is

Its not resizing correctly but once you click on inspect element its resizing. Please help me to find out the solution. The work is more appreciated

Comment: What are you trying to do with resize ?

Comment: Its not resizing according to the size of a div. So some one suggested me to include google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");. But its still not working yet.

Answer (score 0):

In this line

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
           mapOptions);
```

You don't need the 'var'.

Is jquery included ?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and try this way

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
```

Comment: It sounds a problem, when the tab clicked(opened) you should call map.checkResize() , the tab is not visible when you init the gmap, I think its not sizing correctly

Comment: Actually google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize'); is good, call it after the tab is visible

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src ="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script src ="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var map;
var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(13.004558, 77.6017),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

map = new google.maps.Map(
        document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
       mapOptions);

$("#map-canvas").css("height", "120px");
google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
});

</script>
<div id = "map-canvas"></div>
```

Comment: This should work, Please note that you have to set height and width of div in which map will rendered then resize function should be called